# How to return string name of calling method?

Tags: ruby, callstack

Right now my code works as such:

```
def method_a
  self.method_b ==> 'method_b'
end

def method_b
  puts self.name_of_calling_method
end

def name_of_calling_method
  if  /`(.*)'/.match(caller.first)
    return $1
  else
    return nil
  end
end
```

Instead of method_b printing 'method_b', how can I print the name of the calling method - 'method_a'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `caller.first` with `caller[1]`.

Answer (score 3):

When you are in `name_of_calling_method` called from `method_b` then `method_a` is 1 entry higher up the call stack so you want `caller[1]` in `name_of_calling_method` rather than `caller.first` or `caller[0]`.

Because you've put the regexp on the left hand side and the the index into `caller` on the right you won't need an additional `nil` check for the case where `method_b` is called directly and `caller[1]` is `nil` - your *no match* `else` case will cover it.